# Applications of logic in theoretical and practical Computer Science

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science, examples, textbook-recommendation, applications

Can anyone suggest theoretical and/or practical applications of logic (modal, dynamic, Lukasiewici etc.) in Computer Science (like Markov Chains for linear algebra), as well as some open-source books or papers from which I can study by self?. I know for example that $PDL$ (Propositional Dynamic Logic) is used in

> formalizing correctness specifications and proving rigorously that those specifications are met by a particular program. Other activities fall into
>   this category as well: determining the equivalence of programs, comparing the
>   expressive power of various programming constructs, synthesizing programs from specifications, etc. ([Harel, Kozen, Tyurin - Dynamic Logic](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~harel/papers/DynamicLogicHarelKozenTiuryn.pdf))

However, such examples as the one above are too broad. I'd like to know more concrete, hands-on applications, if possible.

Comment: Are you primarily interested in what I might call "non-classical" logics, i.e., logics *other than* classical propositional and predicate logic? What about type theory? Type theory is heavily used in modern proof assistants, but I'm not sure if you consider that to be "logic".

Comment: [This paper](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1923&context=compsci) - aptly titled "On the Unusual Effectiveness of Logic in Computer Science" - may be of interest.

Comment: Formal theories can be treated as formal grammars (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar).

Comment: This is not a research-level question, nor is it a research-level reference request. And in any case, much better answers can be expected from computer scientists than from mathematicians, so I would suggest to move over to cs.stackexchange.com. I will answer the question over there, but not here.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I asked it on cs.stackexchange